# Can I invoke Ant build on Eclipse Save?

Tags: eclipse

Is this possible, if so, how?

In Eclipse, I want to be able to invoke a specific Ant task when I save a file of type "xhtml".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to define a new Builder.  Right click on your project and go to Properties -> Builders.  Then you can create a new Builder that can execute your ant task each time you save if your workspace is configured to build automatically every time you save.

Comment: Does the builder get invoked if all I do is save an xhtml page? (i.e. not java code)

Comment: You can specify the relevant resources that you want the builder to be invoked on.  If you edit your builder configuration, there is a 'Build Options' tab with an option to 'Specify working set of relevant resources'.  If you select that option, you can then specify the resources that the builder applies to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was exactly what I need too (especialy second part of your answer in comment).